# Visual Studio - Sabre GetReservationRS not showing travel items in Intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wsdl, soap-client, sabre

I'm trying to implement the new GetReservationRQ/RS API as the old TravelItineraryReadRQ is apparently being sunset in December 2018.

I am able to make the call and get a response, and all of the valid travel data is present in the XML payload, but I am unable to get Intellisense to show the items in the Item field of the proxy class. I maybe explaining that incorrectly so I have a few screenshots below.

I've tried digging through the reference.cs file created by the WSDL and I do see some differences in the way the object models are created between GetReservationRQ and TravelItinerarReadRQ, but I'm at a loss as to what to do about it.

Populated Object in debug mode showing all of the valid Reservation Items:

[image]

Intellisense showing item field without any other visible members:

[image]

*EDIT 7/26/18*

Thanks to Carlos' answer below, I got this working by implementing his changes. For future generations, here is my working code:

```
public class GetReservationReq
{

    private GetReservationService service;
    public GetReservationRS response;
    public string xmlResponse;

    public GetReservationReq()
    {
        //parameterless constructor for serializiation
    }

    public GetReservationReq(SessionToken token, string locator)
    {
        //MessageHeader
        MessageHeader mHeader = new MessageHeader();

        PartyId[] pId = { new PartyId() };
        pId[0].Value = "SWS";

        From from = new From();
        from.PartyId = pId;

        To to = new To();
        to.PartyId = pId;

        mHeader.Action = "getReservationRQ";
        mHeader.Service = new Service()
        {
            Value = mHeader.Action
        };
        mHeader.ConversationId = token.conversationID;
        mHeader.CPAId = token.ipcc;
        mHeader.From = from;
        mHeader.To = to;
        mHeader.MessageData = new MessageData()
        {
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
        };

        //Security
        Security sec = new Security();
        //Security1 sec = new Security1();
        sec.BinarySecurityToken = token.securityToken;

        //Service
        service = new GetReservationService();
        service.MessageHeaderValue = mHeader;
        service.SoapVersion = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11;
        service.SecurityValue = sec;

        //create the request
        GetReservationRQ req = new GetReservationRQ();
        req.Version = "1.18.0";
        req.RequestType = "Stateful"; //This indicates that we are looking to pull up an existing PNR
        req.Locator = locator;
        req.ReturnOptions = new ReturnOptions();
        req.ReturnOptions.ViewName = "Full";
        req.ReturnOptions.ResponseFormat = "STL";


        try
        {
            //execute the response
            response = service.GetReservationOperation(req);
            //cast response items to usable Object 
            ReservationPNRB content = (ReservationPNRB)response.Item;
            //testing - iterate through reservation elements and do stuff
            foreach (var segment in content.OpenReservationElements.OpenReservationElement)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(segment.id + " - " + segment.type);
            }
            Console.Read();

            //serialize the response for logging if necessary
            xmlResponse = Serializer.toXML(response);


            //serialize response for logging if necessary
            using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\SABRE_DATA\TMP\xmlItin.txt", true))
            {
                XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetReservationRS));
                mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, response);
                StringWriter myStringWriter = new StringWriter();
                mySerializer.Serialize(myStringWriter, response);
                xmlResponse = myStringWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see in your last print screen the Item property is of type Object. That means that you need to cast it to the specific type you are expecting.

To find the valid types that can be returned in that property you need to go to reference.cs, in there you will see on the top of the property (as an attribute) the valid type of objects that the API can return in this property.

Comment: Excellent - thank you so much! It took a bit of monkeying around with the cast but I think I have what I need by casing the response.Item to a "ReservationPNRB" object type.

Comment: Im glad it worked, just be aware that this Item object can returned several types, not only the one you expecting so make sure to verify it first.

Comment: Following up on this - the original cast does work and I can return a fair amount of data properly, but I am running into the same problem down the line with nested object classes. For Example, I can pull back a list of segments, but within the list of segments, each 'Item' field is still listed as the generic 'Object' type. When I try casting that to what I believe to be the lower level of class, I still can't see the class members in Intellisense. Is this a WSDL issue or am I just a total dope and missing something here?

Comment: Kind of answering my own question here as I found the generic type in the reference file and it uses the "[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Air", typeof(SegmentTypePNRBSegmentAir))]" to indicate the allowable types. I'm still struggling with why the data is organized that way, but I think I understand how it works. I guess I'll just have to keep casting on each of the items I get and work around this. Thanks again for your help, Carlos.

Comment: No mention @drtrobridge, but yes this is the way .net proxy generates the classes for Sabre and you should take a look as you have said to the allowed types.I would suggest that you create a factory for the objects you find this behavior so it's easier for you to handle and to centralize the behavior when you are not able to find the expected types.